# Derive next HD segwit address from xpub/ypub

Tags: api, public-key, bip32-hd-wallets, javascript, xpub

I've been using the [smartbit api](https://www.smartbit.com.au/api) to derive the next receiving address for a while now. However it only works for Legacy addresses and not Segwit addresses. I now have a Ledger Nano s and need a similar api to obtain the next address in my HD wallet without having to open Ledger Live. Is there such a service? If not, how can I calculate a series of addresses using the xpub / ypub only. (Javascript if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ Enter your xpub into the `BIP32 Root Key` box and in the BIP141 tab select the derivation path and address type.

Answer (score 0):

There are few utilities now that let you derive addresses from a segwit xpub

**Web Services**

- [blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co)
- [blockpath](https://blockpath.com/)

**Open Source Projects**

- [BitcoinJsLib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib)
- [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin)