# CLI Tool or API for btc address generation given a xpub

Tags: api, xpub, cli

I'd like to script a short tool on the commandline. Therefore I need all used addresses of my wallets derived from a given xpubs.

Don't like to implement it by myself. Is there an already implemented API oder CLI-Tool which derives the addresses and comunicates with bitcoind, electrs ... and checks whether the addresses were used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derive next HD segwit address from xpub/ypub](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80824/derive-next-hd-segwit-address-from-xpub-ypub)